# Normal Distribution on Light Bulb

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

A certain type of lightbulb has an output that is normally distributed with mean 2,000 end foot candles and standard deviation 85 end foot candles. Determine a lower specification limit L so that only 5 percent of the lightbulbs produced will be defective. (That is, determine L so that P{X >= L} = .95, where X is the output of a bulb.)

I have tried to solve this solution but I am stuck on the second step:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In modern statistical language what you want is the $0.05$ **quantile** or $5\%$ **percentile** of a $\text{Normal}(\mu=2000,\sigma=75)$, that is, the value $q$ such that $\text{Pr}(X\le q)=0.05$, with $X$ being a random variable with $\text{Normal}(\mu=2000,\sigma=75)$ pdf.

In Wolfram Alpha you can find it directly using

> Quantile[NormalDistribution[2000, 75], 0.05]

In software R you can use

> qnorm(0.05,2000,75)

In the old fashion way, using probabilities from a standard normal distribution in book tables, you would use the fact that

$$\text{Pr}(X\le q)=0.05=\text{Pr}\left(\underbrace{\frac{X-2000}{75}}_{Z}\le \underbrace{\frac{q-2000}{75}}_{z^*}\right)$$

and notice that $$Z=\frac{X-2000}{75}\sim \text{Normal}(0,1)$$ has a standard normal distribution. Then you would find in the table the value of $z^*$, the 0.05 quantile of a standard normal, and solve for $q$ the equation
$$ \frac{q-2000}{75}=z^*$$

Using any of the previous approaches you should find $q=1876.64$.